# Nextjs dynamic route redirect to 404 after certain days

Tags: reactjs, next.js, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I'm encountering an issue with Next.js 12.3.1 where some dynamic routes unexpectedly redirect to the 404 page after a period of time (randomly sometimes it works for 1 week, sometimes for 2 weeks), despite initially functioning correctly. This behaviour occurs sporadically, affecting only certain routes.

APIs are working perfectly and no any problem with the APIs.

My Code:

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async ({ params }) => {
  const paramSlug = Array.isArray(params?.slug)
    ? params?.slug && params?.slug.length > 0
      ? params?.slug?.join('/')
      : ''
    : params?.slug;

  try {
    if (!paramSlug) {
      throw new Error('Not found!');
    }

    const api = new Api();
    const { body }: { body: any } = await api.get(paramSlug);
    const payload = body?.payload as IResourcePage;
    // if body is null then throw error
    if (!payload) {
      throw new Error(body.message);
    }
    const seo = (body?.seo_data || null) as string | null;

    return {
      props: {
        seo,
        pageData: payload || null,
      },
    };
  } catch (error: any) {
    return {
      notFound: true,
    };
  }
};
```

Can anyone provide insights or solutions to diagnose and address this problem?"